# MATLAB concatenate string variables

Tags: string, matlab

I know `strjoin` can be used to concatenate strings, like `'a'` and  `'b'` but what if one of the strings is a variable, like

`a=strcat('file',string(i),'.mat')`

and I want:

`strjoin({'rm',a})`

MATLAB throws an error when I attempt this, and it's driving me crazy!

`Error using strjoin (line 53) First input must be a string array or cell array of character vectors`

Comment: Why not just use `strcat` again? `strjoin` is, [per the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html), for joining strings contained in an array.

Comment: `sprintf()` will also do the job.

Comment: It helps to include the error.

Comment: Sorry, the error is there now

Comment: RE: your edit, MATLAB's `string` and `char` classes are not the same. Per `strcat`'s documentation, if any input is a `string`, then the output is a `string`, so `a` is a string. `'rm'` is not a string, it's a character vector, so the cell array you edited in is not a cell array of character vectors. I don't agree with MATLAB's unyielding differentiation of `string` and `char`, but the error message is sufficiently explanatory. `strcat('rm', a)` still works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What version of MATLAB are you using? What is the error? The first input to strjoin needs to be a cell array. Try strjoin({'rm'},a).

Also, before 17a, do:

```
a = strcat('file', num2str(i),'.mat')
```

In >=17a do:

```
a = "file" + i + ".mat";
```

Here is a performance comparison:

```
function profFunc

    tic;
    for i = 1:1E5
        a = strcat('file', num2str(i),'.mat');
    end
    toc;

    tic;
    for i = 1:1E5
        a = "file" + i + ".mat";
    end
    toc;
end

>> profFunc
Elapsed time is 6.623145 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.179527 seconds.
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize I could use '+' in recent versions